# Should the comma be em dash in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction, commas, em-dash

In this following context, is the simple type of second part ''there exists not even for the life span...'' ?

Should the comma (,) after the word ''persistent'' be ''em dash (–)''?

Because I think the second part gave specific information on preceding state.

Explain this to me please...

the context:

> Within these phenomena there exists nothing that is persistent, not
> even for the brief span of two consecutive moments.

Source:
page.7
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Answer (score 1):

An emdash would work, but the comma also works.

The word "even" here occupies the same role as the bolded words in sentences like these:

> MSN Messenger was discontinued in 2013, **partly** because Skype chat was meant to replace it.

> You are here for a reason, **whether** or not you perceive it.

This is a common use of the comma.

I would probably prefer the comma in your example because the emdash jars very slightly with the reverent tone, but I'm sure someone else might prefer the emdash stylistically.

Comment: Do you say 'partly and whether' there are the same role with 'even'? Yes, some also recommended that ''You can use an em-dash if you like; both are common for marking parentheses.'' Thanks @Luke Sawczak.